# How to get the latest not null value from multiple columns in SQL or Azure Synapse

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I have data like in the below format

[image]

I want output in the below format

[image]

Please help me with the SQL code. Thanks !

Comment: This seems like you have a design flaw in your data, if I am honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mention in the comments, you *need* to fix whatever it is that's inserting the data and not lose the values so that they become `NULL` in "newer" rows.

To get the results you want, you'll going to have to use row numbering and conditional aggregation, which is going to get messy the more columns you have; and why you **need** to fix the *real* problem. This will look something like this:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT GroupingColumn,
           NullableCol1,
           NullableCol2,
           DateColumn,
           CASE WHEN NullableCol1 IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupingColumn, CASE WHEN NullableCol1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY DateColumn DESC) AS NullableCol1RN,
           CASE WHEN NullableCol2 IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupingColumn, CASE WHEN NullableCol2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY DateColumn DESC) AS NullableCol2RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT GroupingColumn,
       MAX(CASE NullableCol1RN WHEN 1 THEN NullableCol1 END) AS NullableCol1,
       MAX(CASE NullableCol2RN WHEN 1 THEN NullableCol2 END) AS NullableCol2,
       MAX(DateColumn) AS DateColumn
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Thank You for your valuable suggestions and code. This helps a lot !